# Text Entry on an Android Custom View

Tags: android, text, textview

I'm dealing with a phone that has no physical keyboard and I'm using my own custom view for rendering.  The device I'm working with, by default, seems to be in a T9 type entry mode where it suggests blocks of text.  However, it never sends me the actual key events.

How do I tell whatever soft-keyboard that pops up to enter 'dumb' key event sending mode?

The InputMethodManager has a "isAcceptinText()" call which would tell me if it's in event-sending mode, but not a method to set it.  Digging through the documentation hasn't produced any insight.  How do I tell the input manager that I only want key events?

Answer (score 1):

I think this page has pretty much all there is to say on Android Input method control:  [Android - Onscreen Input Methods](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link but it seems to have only confirmed my own hunting through to documentation.